# How to query on a generic model using EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics, reflection

I am developing an MVC 5 application. I query on my database as:

```
var result = db.ABCs.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == Id);
```

But what if I want to make a generic method and Don't know the name of the model on compile time. I want to query on any model class that is passed to a method at runtime.
Something as :

```
var result = db.<T>.Where(x => x.Id == Id).ToList();
```

How can I do that. I am using database first approach and no repositories or UoW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to give some information about `Id` property. You can do it creating interface with common for all entities properties:

```
interface IEntity
{
    int Id {get;}
}
```

And implement it in your classes:

```
class ABC : IEntity
{
    int Id {get; set;} 
    string Name {get;set;}
}

List<T> GetData<T>(int id) where T : class, IEntity
{
    var result = db.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Id == Id).ToList();
    return result;
}

...

var data = GetData<ABC>(10);
```

Comment: I'm curious if this would work without a base class, using dynamic. Something like `db.Set<T>().Where(x => ((dynamic)x).Id == Id).ToList();`

Comment: @Dominik I think no, EF don't like `dynamic` :)

Comment: Too bad, that would be awesome